# What would be the best way to track by $index in nested ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in grid track by $index">
    <div cell class="cell" ng-repeat="cell in row track by $index" ng-click="game.addItem($index, $index)">
        {{cell.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to track by index in the first ng-repeat and in the second, in order to pass them off to addItem(). What would be the best way to pass both of them?

Comment: I haven't tried it but is $index put on the variable i.e. row.$index cell.$index - why not just pass the row and cell in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I belieive you can do:

```
<div class="row" 
     ng-repeat="row in grid track by $index" 
     ng-init="$rowIndex = $index">
  <div cell class="cell" 
       ng-repeat="cell in row track by $index" 
       ng-click="game.addItem($rowIndex, $index)">
    {{cell.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

(Init might need to go on the outer div, can't recall as I sit here)

Although the question would beg, why can't you just use the cell and row, what do you specifically need the indexes for.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm trying to write an app that's completely decoupled from angular. I need to know which row the cell was clicked in and which cell had the click.

Comment: Btw, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. And you were right, ng-init was supposed to go on the outer div in order for them to pass on separately.

Comment: Ok, didn't have the time to test it, fixed the example now so it should be correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in grid track by $index">
    <div cell class="cell" ng-repeat="cell in row track by $index" 
       ng-click="game.addItem(row, cell)">
        {{cell.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```